# Replacing strings like {{Asd}} using RegEx

Tags: php, regex, arrays, function

My understanding of regular expressions is nearly 0 and I'm searching for an expression that replaces all expressions like `{{AWord}}` in a (PHP) string using preg_replace.

```
(\{\{\w\}\})
```

I hoped this works but it doesn't.

Example:

**This is {{just}} a {{SHORT0}} example.**

Expected Output :

**This is a example.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `~{{(.*?)}}~`

```
<?php
$str='This is {{just}} a {{SHORT0}} example.';
echo $str = preg_replace("~{{(.*?)}}~","", $str);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
This is a example.
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/124435)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but `\w` matches only a single character (a letter, digit or underscore). Use

```
(\{\{\w+\}\})
```

- The `+` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) means "one or more"
- `*` means "zero or more"
- `?` means "zero or one"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'll not have any `{` or `}` inside the `{{...}}`

```
(\{\{[^\}]*\}\})
```

`[^\}]*` means any character other than `}`